# Evitar la redirección con PHP

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Tengo mi archivo php validatecredentials.php que me permite validar si el usuario y la contraseña es correcta. Y lo que sucede es que cuando inicio sesion, ya sea que la contraseña o el usuario esté correcto o incorrecto, cuando presiono el botón, me redirige me dirige a mi archivo validatecredentials.php

Este es mi código que mantengo en mi archivo PHP validate credentials:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$contra = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contra', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$hashedContra = hash("sha256", $contra);
$host = "**";
$username = "**";
$password = "**";
$dbname = "**";

//Crear la conexion SQL
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Conexión fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT email, password FROM webcustomers WHERE email = ? AND password =?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $hashedContra);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Guarda la cookie encriptada
    $hashedCookieEmail = hash("sha256", $email);
    $hashedCookiePass = hash("sha256", $contra);
    setcookie("emailUsuario", $hashedCookieEmail, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    setcookie("contraUsuario", $hashedCookiePass, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    ob_start();
    header('Location: https://strant.store/tienda.php');
    exit();
  } else {
    echo "<script>swal({
          title: 'No se ha podido iniciar sesión',
          text: 'Contraseña o email incorrectos',
          icon: 'error',
          button: 'Ups',
        });</script>";
  }
  

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Y este es el fragmento de HTML en el que tengo mi form:

```
<form class="bg-white" method="post" action="validatecredentials.php">
                    <h1 class="text-gray-800 font-bold text-2xl mb-1">Hola de Nuevo!</h1>
                    <p class="text-sm font-normal text-gray-600 mb-7">Un gusto tenerte nuevamente</p>
                    <div class="flex items-center border-2 py-2 px-3 rounded-2xl mb-4">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                            fill="currentColor">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 9a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6zm-7 9a7 7 0 1114 0H3z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                        <input class="pl-2 outline-none border-none" type="email" name="email" id="email"
                            placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>


                    <div class="flex items-center border-2 py-2 px-3 rounded-2xl">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                            fill="currentColor">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M5 9V7a5 5 0 0110 0v2a2 2 0 012 2v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5a2 2 0 012-2zm8-2v2H7V7a3 3 0 016 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                        <input class="pl-2 outline-none border-none" type="password" name="contra" id="contra"
                            placeholder="Contraseña" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit"
                        class="block w-full bg-green-600 mt-4 py-2 rounded-2xl text-white font-semibold mb-2">Iniciar
                        Sesión</button>

                    <span class="text-sm ml-2 hover:text-blue-500 cursor-pointer">Olvidaste tu contraseña</span>
                </form>
```

No logro dar con el error por lo que me puede estar sucediendo esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando utilizas un botón para hacer `submit` en un formulario a un archivo PHP vas a redirigir sí o sí. Tienes varias opciones:

- Redirigir nuevamente al formulario de inicio de sesión en caso de que algo falle.
- Hacer la validación usando Javascript para hacerlo 'en tiempo real'.
- Realizar una petición `AJAX` para que no redirija.

Yo preferiría la segunda y tercera opción, por amigabilidad para el usuario. Mucha redirección es algo incómodo.

He visto que utilizas `sha256` para el hasheo de las contraseñas. Se recomienda utilizar la función `password_hash` para mayor seguridad. A continuación dejo el enlace, tanto de la documentación como de un post relacionado por si te es de ayuda.

[PHP: password_hash - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)

[Pregunta en StackOverflow - EN donde se habla de la encirptación y hasheo de contraseñas. Mirar la respuesta aceptada.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371346/can-a-hashed-password-by-md5-be-replaced-by-sha-256-password)